# не удаляется класс при нажатии

Tags: php, jquery

класс active не удаляется при нажатии на другую кнопку

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs text-center" id="cTabs" >
        <li><a href="/" class="active">bütün mallar</a></li>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $categoryItem): ?>

        <li >
            <a href="/category/<?php echo $categoryItem['id']; ?>" 
                class="" >
                <?php echo $categoryItem['name']; ?>
            </a>
        </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

вот скрипт:

```
 $("#cTabs li a").click(function(){

      $("#cTabs li a .active").removeClass("active");

      $(this).addClass("active");

    });
```

Comment: потому что обработчик стоит на `li`, а кликаешь, скорее всего, на `a`...... кстати в итоге ты `active` потом тоже добавляешь в `li`

Comment: не,эт опечатка была,исправил

Comment: тогда еще раз пересмотри код ....... `a .active` ....... пробел не смущает? Хотя там вообще должно быть просто так `$("#cTabs li a").removeClass("active");` Просто на всякий случай, чтобы снять активность со всех

Comment: все равно нет ,он как бы сначала убирает на секунду,потом опять перебрасывает на 1й элемент

Comment: дело даже не в удалении,а в том что он не добавляет класс другому элементу

Comment: окей... ты не сделал `e.preventDefault()` из-за которого срабатывает дефолтное поведение ссылки, а именно, отправляет на указанный `url`..... в данном случае на тот же самый..... что вызывает перезагрузку страницы.. всё логично

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#cTabs li a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#cTabs li a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
ul.nav li a.active {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs text-center" id="cTabs">
  <li><a href="/" class="active">bütün mallar</a></li>
  <li><a href="/category/1" class="">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/category/2" class="">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/category/3" class="">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="/category/4" class="">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Cheg ,теперь кнопки-то работают,но ссылки нет

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $("#cTabs li a .active").removeClass("active");
> ```

```
$("#cTabs li a.active").removeClass("active");
//            ^--- тут нет пробела
```

Comment: у него еще `preventDefault` не хватает

Comment: сделал я e preventDefault,кнопки переключаются,но по ссылкам не переходит

Comment: понял? по ссылкам теперь не переходит. Поломали!

Comment: @TofiqŞamedov - Выбирайте что-то одно: или Вы изменяете свойства DOM-элементов и остаетесь на той же странице, или Вы грузите другую страницу и устанавливаете класс активному элементу во время генерации/загрузки страницы.

Comment: понятно,спасибо